# Can あなたはなんで会社へいきますか mean "How did you get to work?" (such as via what means)

Tags: usage

Can あなたはなんで会社へいきますか mean "How did you get to work?" as in what method did you use to get to work (train, bus, etc.) or can it only mean the literal translation of "Why do you go to work?"

Comment: It can mean both, context will generally tell which one it is.

Comment: `Can あなたはなんで会社へいきますか mean "How did you get to work?"` -- 「いきま**す**か」 is the present tense.